# Force Entity Framework 6 (EF6) to use nvarchar(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I thought this would be easy, but...

How do you force EF6 to use `nvarchar(MAX)`?

I've tried:

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
```

and

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
[MaxLength()]
```

and

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Date>().Property(o => o.test).HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)");
```

I'm using EF6.2.0 and SQL2014 Express

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you do not specify a length then EF Code First defaults to nvarchar(max), so if you specify a Name column:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

you will get an nvarchar(max) column.

If you need to specify a length, say 100 chars then you would specify the column in code:

```
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

If you need to specify varchar rather than nvarchar you would use this:

```
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
[MaxLength(50)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

see [Code First Conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), [Code First Data Annotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/stringlength-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) and [Column Annotations](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: You're right. I was checking my table schema using sp_columns, which returns `ntext` instead of `nvarchar`, so I thought it wasn't defining the column correctly. Thanks

Comment: You should use `[MaxLength(100)]` on database-models instead of `StringLength`. `StringLength` is used for data validation on view-models. (Yeah, I know, they do work both here with `string`) Well, `StringLength`doesn't work for `byte[]`, just `MaxLength` and `MinLength`. Plus, if you use `StringLength`, which works on viewmodel-validation too, you could drift into using database-models in your views, which is a bad design.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me in Entity Framework Core 5<

```
[Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
[MaxLength(int.MaxValue)]
public string ImageBase64 { get; set; }
```

Generates the following migration:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "ImageBase64",
    table: "Medias",
    type: "nvarchar(MAX)",
    maxLength: 2147483647,
    nullable: true,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)",
    oldMaxLength: 450,
    oldNullable: true);
```

`MaxLength` needed since we modify OnModelCreating to avoid `nvarchar(MAX)` for all string columns.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties())
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
    {
        if (property.GetMaxLength() == null)
            property.SetMaxLength(450);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of typing it everywhere you can also set it by default to your required length.
Override the function **OnModelCreating** in you **dbcontext** class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var property in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties()).Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
    {
        if (property.GetMaxLength() == null)
        {
            property.SetMaxLength(256);
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.GetColumnType()))
        {
            property.SetColumnType("varchar");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but there's no `Model` inside `modelBuilder`; apparently this is for .Net Core only.